# How to group results with conditions?

Tags: mysql

I cannot solve this problem for many hours.
This is my table

```
t1:

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| id | text   |  lang | transl_id |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| 1  | first  |  en   |  222      |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| 2  | second |  de   |  222      |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| 3  |   jkj  |  de   |  234      |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| 4  |  89080 |  de   |  235      |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    transl_id AS property,
    (SELECT text FROM t1 WHERE lang='en') AS value1,
    (SELECT text FROM t1 WHERE lang='de') AS value2,

FROM t1
```

It returns following table:

```
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| property  |  value1  |  value2  |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|    222    |  first   |          |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|    222    |          |  second  |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|    234    |  jkj     |          |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|    235    |  89080   |          |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Each row has either `value1` or `value2`, never both. Is there a way to group results so that rows with equal values for `property` field would be in one row? I mean something like this:

```
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| property  |  value1  |  value2  |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|    222    |  first   |  second  |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
...
```

Comment: `... group by property, value1, value2`?

Comment: @MarcB: Take a closer look at the question, I don't think that's it. The title is misleading. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Excuse me for being unclear. Give a minute, I'll update the question and add details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    property,
    max(value1) as Value1,
    max(value2) as Value2
FROM 
(
SELECT transl_id AS property,
    CASE when lang = 'en' then text else null end as value1,
    CASE when lang = 'de' then text else null end as value2
FROM t1
) t
GROUP BY property
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbabe/14)

Tried adding more values in the table and got the desired result [in this SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8a81/1)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
select t1.property, t1.value1, t2.value2 from
( select property, value1 from table1 where value1 is not null ) t1,
( select property, value2 from table1 where value2 is not null ) t2
where t1.property = t2.property
```